# Firestore Query Listener

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I listen to changes to a collection with a listener

`query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>()`

When I add first document, listener gets it and it works as I want it to, but then when I add the second document my listener gets this second document **and** the first one again, then with 3rd it records this 3rd document and the rest 2, and so on.

Can I make it that my listener gets only latest document when it is added, not all of the documents?

EDIT:

```
query = chatCollectionRef.whereEqualTo("receiverID", userID).whereEqualTo("senderID", targetID);
            registration = query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("ListenerError", "Listen Failed");
                        return;
                    }

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        Log.d("ListenerLog", "New Document in Listener")
                        Item item= doc.toObject(Item.class);
                        itemList.add(item);
                        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                  }
                }
```

The problem is that when first document is added my listener and recyclerview shows this [image]

And then, when i add second document, listener gets all two of them, not only the latest one, and my recyclerView looks like this

[image]

Comment: Please show the [minimal, complete listener that is needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now we're missing both what `query` is, and how you handle the `QuerySnapshot`.

Comment: Post your code with database structure

Comment: Please add the code that you using and please also responde with @.

Answer (score 2):

Snapshot will always returned the complete data,
if you want to get only the changes in the datqa you should use the following code as documented in firestore:

```
    db.collection("cities").whereEqualTo("state", "CA").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() 
    {

        @Override
                    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot snapshots,
                                        @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "listen:error", e);
                        return;
                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : snapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                        switch (dc.getType()) {
                            case ADDED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "New city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case MODIFIED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "Modified city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                            case REMOVED:
                                Log.d(TAG, "Removed city: " + dc.getDocument().getData());
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Query listener always sends ONLY the documents that have changed but the firebase client SDK combines it with other documents and delivers them to you so that you don't have to write the logic for write specific code for different conditions. You should check the following video by Firebase team in which they explain "how to implement the real-time feature with firestore"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3aoxOtMM2rc&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=10